# How to change text colors in Calendar?

Tags: software-installation

Can I change the text or background color in the Calendar? I'm using 22.04 and the default is white text against a light blue/green background and it is very difficult to read.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1470259/edit) and post a screenshot?